# Android Studio and gradle build server

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Im developing an Android app on a lightweight ultra book running Arch linux. My laptop has no problem with running Android Studio, but doesn't really like compiling the app. The compilation is slow and some times runs out of memory.

Is it possible to set up grade to build remotely on a faster computer without too much hassle, still having all the installing/debugging features in Android Studio?

Comment: Maybe you can play with JVM permsize parameters on Eclipse and Gradle files to allocate less or more memory to build your app

Comment: As I only have 4 GB RAM, this is not an option. I have already increased it, but this causes other applications to  crash

Comment: I'm developping also with 4Gb of RAM on a ultrabook and it works well. If your Eclipse has no problem, I would decrease the permsize of Eclipse and increase the permsize of Gradle to test. Furthermore, it's cracsh on compiling or when you deploy on emulator/device ?

Comment: It crashes during compilation. And I'm using Android Studio and not Eclipse :) Ill give Jenkis a try!